# How to solve "#2006 - MySQL server has gone away" AND "ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

When I'm trying to browse a table in phpmyadmin, it outputs "`#2006 - MySQL server has gone away`" as error. Please help to find a solution for this problem. I'm using lampp in ubuntu12.04. And also it output as error "`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query`" from ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Check interactive_timeout and wait_timeout in my.cnf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the max_allowed_packet setting to a larger value in the server.

Open "my.ini/cnf", located in your MySQL installation folder, and under `[mysqld]` section change `"max_allowed_packet = 64M"` and don't forget to restart the server. You can check the value by executing:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Dear Sathish, I'm already edited my.cnf with max_allowed_packet = 64M, but no use.

Answer (score 0):

It you constantly get this when you query the same table then that table is most probably corrupt. Which means that the MySQL thread dies, hence the `"has gone away"` message.

Repair the table and if the problems persist, upgrade the server are the options I have for you.